# How can I perform matrix-vector-multiplication using the * operator in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, operator-overloading, matrix-multiplication, multiplication, vector-multiplication

I want to overload the multiplication operator in Python.
What I exactly want to do is to multiply a 4x4 matrix with
a 4D vector.

```py
import math
class Vec4():
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 0):
        """Constructor for Vec4
        DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD"""
        self.values = [x,y,z,w]

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the vector as a string representation
        DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD"""
        toReturn = ''
        if self is None: return '0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00'
        for c in range(0,4):
                toReturn += "%.2f" % self.values[c]
                if c != 3:
                    toReturn += ' '
        return toReturn

class Matrix4():
    def __init__(self, row1=None, row2=None, row3=None, row4=None):
        """Constructor for Matrix4
        DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD"""
        if row1 is None: row1 = Vec4()
        if row2 is None: row2 = Vec4()
        if row3 is None: row3 = Vec4()
        if row4 is None: row4 = Vec4()
        self.m_values = [row1,row2,row3,row4]

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the matrix
        DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD"""
        toReturn = ''
        if self is None: return '0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00\n0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00\n0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00\n0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00'
        for r in range(0,4):
            for c in range(0,4):
                toReturn += "%.2f" % self.m_values[r].values[c]
                if c != 3:
                    toReturn += ' '
            toReturn += '\n'
        return toReturn

    def __mul__(self, v):
        """Element wise multiplication of self by vector v
        Returns the result as a new vector"""
        x = self.m_values[0][0]*self.values[0]+self.m_values[0][1]*self.values[1]+self.m_values[0][2]*self.values[2]+self.m_values[0][3]*self.values[3]
        y = self.m_values[1][0]*self.values[0]+self.m_values[1][1]*self.values[1]+self.m_values[1][2]*self.values[2]+self.m_values[1][3]*self.values[3]
        z = self.m_values[2][0]*self.values[0]+self.m_values[2][1]*self.values[1]+self.m_values[2][2]*self.values[2]+self.m_values[3][3]*self.values[3]
        w = self.m_values[3][0]*self.values[0]+self.m_values[3][1]*self.values[1]+self.m_values[3][2]*self.values[2]+self.m_values[3][3]*self.values[3]
        return Vec4(x,y,z,w)
```

As you can see, I have tried implement it. It doesn't work for me.
The result should be a vector.

```py
A = Matrix4(Vec4(1, 0, 0, 0),
            Vec4(0, 1, 0, 0),
            Vec4(0, 0, 1, 0),
            Vec4(0, 0, 0, 1))
>>> V = Vec4(1,2,3,4)
>>> print(A*V)
```

Result should be "1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00".

But it causes an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    print(A*V)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Download-Stuff\Gmail\TransformMatrix.py", line 45, in __mul__
    x = self.m_values[0].values[0]*self.values[0]+self.m_values[0].values[1]*self.values[1]+self.m_values[0].values[2]*self.values[2]+self.m_values[0].values[3]*self.values[3]
AttributeError: 'Matrix4' object has no attribute 'values'
```

What should I do? What am I doing wrong?
Somebody told me to use nested loops, but I am not familiar with it.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't given `Matrix4` a `.values` attribute - only `.m_values`

Comment: Sure, the Vec4 class has self.values. I am using them.

Answer (score 1):

You have `values` in `Vec4` and `m_values` in `Matrix4`. When you refer to `self` from within the `Matrix4` class this is an instance of `Matrix4` that you are referring to. From within methods in that class, you either need to refer to `self.m_values` to get the array of `Vec4` or `self.m_values[i].values` to access the contents of the `Vec4`.

You might find it easier if you override the index operator for both. e.g., for `Vec4`, include in the class def:

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
    return self.values[i]
def __setitem__(self, i, v):
    self.values[i] = v
```

When you get down to the detail of how to do it, I recommend checking out something like: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34173/fast-matrix-multiplication

Note that [numpy](https://www.numpy.org/) provides efficient matrix multiplication and may save you some trouble.

Comment: Can you exactly show in the code what you would change? That would help me better.

Comment: I have added two comments that might help. For the general problem of how to access an individual value in a vector, look in the code that you already have for `__str__`

Comment: We are not allowed to use Numpy. Can you tell me how to implement the multiplication of two NxN matrices using the * operator?

Comment: Hmm ... sounds like I'm doing your homework :) Perhaps just tell me where you are stuck.